# Three-way comparison of values, count number of 'successes'

Tags: r, comparison, simulation

Let's say I've conducted three types of regression methods on some simulated data (multiple datasets), such that I have a MSE for each of the methods corresponding to each dataset. Some example data (df) could look like this:

```
df
simulation mse_test1 mse_test2 mse_test3
1          60        80        10                   
2          80        20        50
3          10        90        100
4          70        50        10
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to compare each of the 3 MSE values for a given simulation to determine the lowest MSE (i.e. for the first row (simulation 1), I'd like to ascertain the test3 has the lowest MSE). I'd like to do this comparison for all of my simulations, where if a method (test) has the lowest MSE, it will receive a 1, while other methods/test will receive zeros.

In the end, I'd like to store the results of these comparison (in `df_result` so I could find the method (test) with the largest sum of 1s. For example, using our example data, the results would like like this:

```
df_result:
mse_test1 mse_test2 mse_test3
1         1         2
```

I.e., the second method/test has the lowest MSE for the most amount of simulations.

Thanks for any tips!

I'd also to accomplish the same results, but for the data saved in a list as follows:

```
    sample_results
 [[1]]
    mse_test1[[1]]
    60
    mse_test1[[2]]
    80
    mse_test1[[3]]
    10
    mse_test1[[4]]
    70



[[2]]
    mse_test2[[1]]
    80
    mse_test2[[2]]
    20
    mse_test2[[3]]
    90
    mse_test2[[4]]
    50
[[3]]
    mse_test3[[1]]
    10
    mse_test3[[2]]
    50
    mse_test3[[3]]
    100
    mse_test3[[4]]
    10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to use `table` on each row of the data frame

```
table(max.col(-df[-1]))

#1 2 3 
#1 1 2
```

Or,

```
t1 <- table(max.col(-df[-1]))
setNames(t1, paste0('mse_test', names(t1)))

#mse_test1 mse_test2 mse_test3 
#        1         1         2
```

If you have a list of lists then just convert to data frame and follow the same procedure, i.e.

```
d3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(l2, function(i) unlist(i))))
t2 <- table(max.col(-d3))

setNames(t2, paste0('mse_test', names(t2)))

#mse_test1 mse_test2 mse_test3 
#        1         1         2
```

Where,

```
dput(l2)
list(list(60L, 80L, 10L, 70L), list(80L, 20L, 90L, 50L), list(
    10L, 50L, 100L, 10L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What if I had my results in a list? I.e.: mse_test1 would be a list within a list with the 4 mse values.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, that code seems to work well. Would you mind explaining how that code calculates the sequential minimums? I'm curious to know how it works.

Comment: @lecreprays I edited as I found a problem with my previous solution.